# How can I draw speech bubbles like in Mac OS X's iCal in Java?

Tags: java, macos, user-interface

Anyone know how to do draw sth similar to this in Java and working for Linux and or Mac?

We're trying to do an introduction tutorial for JDownloader this way.

[image: A screenshot of what I mean]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called a popover and is an Objective-C component. Your best bet would be to extend JComponent and do a custom component by overriding `paint(Graphics g)`. I dont know of any libraries with the popover, but some google-fu may lead you to one.